# How to update and delete firebase data from table of html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update and delete already retrieved data from html table view. I try the following code but onClick function is not working.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("products");  //Read data to show in table format
    rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var key = snap.key;
    var description = snap.child("description").val();
    var image = snap.child("image").val();

    $("#table_body").append("<tr id='"+snap.key+"'><td>"+ key +"</td><td>" + description + "</td><td>" + image 
                            +"</td><td><button onclick='"+updateData()+"'>Update</button></td><td>"
                            +"</td><td><button onclick='"+deleteData()+"'>Delete</button></td><td>"
                            +"</td></tr>");
    });
```

The table is showed perfectly but button is not working.I am including an image to clear my question.
[image: onClick funtion not working]

how can I update and delete firebase data using table. I want to Prompt a dialog box to update and delete the specific data, but how can I do it?

Comment: You don't want to pass the executed function, so remove the `()` and see if that helps? e.g. `onclick=deleteData`, rather than `onclick=deleteData()`

Comment: You should pass the completely string for function name.  So here should be `<button onclick='updateData()'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the snapshot's [`key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key) corresponding to the table row (i.e. `snap.key`) to your `updateData()` and `deleteData()` functions, as follows:

```
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('products'); //Read data to show in table format
  rootRef.on('child_added', (snap) => {
    
    var key = snap.key;
    var description = snap.child('description').val();
    var image = snap.child('image').val();

    $('#table_body').append(
      "<tr id='" +
        snap.key +
        "'><td>" +
        key +
        '</td><td>' +
        description +
        '</td><td>' +
        image +
        "</td><td><button onclick=updateData('" +
        snap.key +
        "')>Update</button></td><td>" +
        "</td><td><button onclick=deleteData('" +
        snap.key +
        "')>Delete</button></td><td>" +
        '</td></tr>'
    );
  });

  function deleteData(key) {
    rootRef
      .child(key)
      .remove()
      .then(function () {
        console.log('Remove succeeded.');
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Remove failed: ' + error.message);
      });
  }

  function updateData(key) {
    rootRef
      .child(key)
      .update({ foo: 'bar' })
      .then(function () {
        // ...
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // ...
      });
  }
```

---

Note that when you delete a row, your front-end is not updated since you use a 'child_added' event.

Comment: Thanks for responding but this code shows `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error!! What should I do ? Please help!

Comment: You should look at the line where this error occurs and analyse why it is occurring.

Comment: index.html:1 but if I remove snap.ref. this error disappears. I got `https://mybistro.firebaseio.com/products/1` this response from number 1 product.